# A nicer closed form? $\int_0^1 \frac{\log (x) \log \left(x^2-x+1\right)}{x^2-x+2} \, dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Mathematica doesn't return a nice result for the integral below, maybe because such one doesn't exist, or it exists but it depends much on a certain way of tackling things. What do you think?
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\log (x) \log \left(x^2-x+1\right)}{x^2-x+2} \, dx$$

$$=\frac{2 i \log ^3(2)}{3 \sqrt{7}}+\frac{i \log \left(\frac{(-1)^{5/6}}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right) \log ^2(2)}{\sqrt{7}}+\frac{i \log \left(\frac{\left(i+\sqrt{3}\right) \left(1+i \sqrt{7}\right)}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right) \log ^2(2)}{\sqrt{7}}+\frac{i \log \left(\sqrt[6]{-1} \left(1+i \sqrt{7}\right)\right) \log ^2(2)}{\sqrt{7}}+\frac{2 i \log \left(3-i \sqrt{7}\right) \log ^2(2)}{\sqrt{7}}-\frac{i \log \left(\frac{\left(-i+\sqrt{3}\right) \left(1-i \sqrt{7}\right)}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right) \log ^2(2)}{\sqrt{7}}-\frac{i \log \left(i-\sqrt{7}\right) \log ^2(2)}{\sqrt{7}}-\frac{i \log \left(\left(1-i \sqrt{3}\right) \left(-i+\sqrt{7}\right)\right) \log ^2(2)}{\sqrt{7}}-\frac{2 i \log \left(3+i \sqrt{7}\right) \log ^2(2)}{\sqrt{7}}-\frac{\pi  \log ^2(2)}{\sqrt{7}}+\frac{i \log ^2\left(\frac{(-1)^{5/6}}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right) \log (2)}{\sqrt{7}}+\frac{i \log ^2\left(\frac{i-\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right) \log (2)}{\sqrt{7}}+\frac{i \log ^2\left(\frac{\left(-i+\sqrt{3}\right) \left(1-i \sqrt{7}\right)}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right) \log (2)}{\sqrt{7}}+\frac{i \log ^2\left(\left(-1+\sqrt[3]{-1}\right) \left(-i+\sqrt{7}\right)\right) \log (2)}{\sqrt{7}}+\frac{2 i \log (4) \log \left(\frac{i+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right) \log (2)}{\sqrt{7}}+\frac{2 i \log (4) \log \left(\frac{\left(-i+\sqrt{3}\right) \left(1-i \sqrt{7}\right)}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right) \log (2)}{\sqrt{7}}+\frac{2 \pi  \log \left(i-\sqrt{7}\right) \log (2)}{3 \sqrt{7}}+\frac{2 i \log \left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right) \log \left(\left(-1+\sqrt[3]{-1}\right) \left(-i+\sqrt{7}\right)\right) \log (2)}{\sqrt{7}}+\frac{2 i \log \left(i-\sqrt{7}\right) \log \left(\sqrt[6]{-1} \left(1+i \sqrt{7}\right)\right) \log (2)}{\sqrt{7}}+\frac{2 \pi  \log \left(\left(i+\sqrt{3}\right) \left(1+i \sqrt{7}\right)\right) \log (2)}{\sqrt{7}}+\frac{2 i \log \left(\frac{\left(i+\sqrt{3}\right) \left(1+i \sqrt{7}\right)}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right) \log \left(3+i \sqrt{7}\right) \log (2)}{\sqrt{7}}+\frac{4 \pi  \log \left(7+i \sqrt{7}\right) \log (2)}{\sqrt{7}}+\frac{2 i \log \left(\frac{-i+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right) \log \left(3-i \sqrt{7}\right) \log (2)}{\sqrt{7}}+\frac{4 \pi  \log \left(7-i \sqrt{7}\right) \log (2)}{\sqrt{7}}-\frac{i \log ^2\left(\frac{\left(i+\sqrt{3}\right) \left(1+i \sqrt{7}\right)}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right) \log (2)}{\sqrt{7}}-\frac{i \log ^2\left(-\frac{i+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right) \log (2)}{\sqrt{7}}-\frac{4 \pi  \log (7) \log (2)}{\sqrt{7}}-\frac{8 \pi  \log (8) \log (2)}{\sqrt{7}}-\frac{i \log (16) \log \left(i+\sqrt{3}\right) \log (2)}{\sqrt{7}}-\frac{2 i \log (4) \log \left(\frac{-i+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right) \log (2)}{\sqrt{7}}-\frac{2 i \log (4) \log \left(\frac{\left(i+\sqrt{3}\right) \left(1+i \sqrt{7}\right)}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right) \log (2)}{\sqrt{7}}-\frac{2 i \log \left(i+\sqrt{3}\right) \log \left(-i+\sqrt{7}\right) \log (2)}{\sqrt{7}}-\frac{2 i \log \left(\frac{-i+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right) \log \left(-i+\sqrt{7}\right) \log (2)}{\sqrt{7}}-\frac{2 i \log \left(-i+\sqrt{3}\right) \log \left(3+i \sqrt{7}\right) \log (2)}{\sqrt{7}}-\frac{2 i \log \left(\frac{i+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right) \log \left(3+i \sqrt{7}\right) \log (2)}{\sqrt{7}}-\frac{2 i \log \left(\frac{\left(-i+\sqrt{3}\right) \left(1-i \sqrt{7}\right)}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right) \log \left(3-i \sqrt{7}\right) \log (2)}{\sqrt{7}}-\frac{\pi  \log (64) \log (2)}{3 \sqrt{7}}-\frac{4 \pi  \log \left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right) \log (2)}{3 \sqrt{7}}-\frac{2 \pi  \log \left(\left(1-i \sqrt{3}\right) \left(-i+\sqrt{7}\right)\right) \log (2)}{3 \sqrt{7}}+\frac{503 \pi ^3}{648 \sqrt{7}}+\frac{i \log ^3\left(\frac{(-1)^{5/6}}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right)}{3 \sqrt{7}}+\frac{i \log ^3\left(\frac{i-\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right)}{3 \sqrt{7}}+\frac{i \log ^3\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right)}{3 \sqrt{7}}+\frac{i \log ^3\left(\left(-1+\sqrt[3]{-1}\right) \left(-i+\sqrt{7}\right)\right)}{3 \sqrt{7}}+\frac{i \log (4) \log ^2\left(-i-\sqrt{3}\right)}{\sqrt{7}}+\frac{i \log (64) \log ^2\left(-i+\sqrt{3}\right)}{3 \sqrt{7}}+\frac{\pi  \log ^2\left(\frac{\left(i+\sqrt{3}\right) \left(1+i \sqrt{7}\right)}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right)}{3 \sqrt{7}}+\frac{\pi  \log ^2\left(\frac{\left(-i+\sqrt{3}\right) \left(1-i \sqrt{7}\right)}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right)}{3 \sqrt{7}}+\frac{i \log (8) \log ^2\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right)}{3 \sqrt{7}}+\frac{i \log \left(\frac{\left(i+\sqrt{3}\right) \left(1+i \sqrt{7}\right)}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right) \log ^2\left(-\frac{i+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right)}{\sqrt{7}}+\frac{i \log \left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right) \log ^2\left(\left(-1+\sqrt[3]{-1}\right) \left(-i+\sqrt{7}\right)\right)}{\sqrt{7}}+\frac{\pi  \log ^2\left(\sqrt[6]{-1} \left(1+i \sqrt{7}\right)\right)}{3 \sqrt{7}}+\frac{2 i \pi ^2 \log \left(-i+\sqrt{3}\right)}{3 \sqrt{7}}+\frac{i \log (4) \log (64) \log \left(-i+\sqrt{3}\right)}{3 \sqrt{7}}+\frac{i \log ^2\left(\frac{\left(i+\sqrt{3}\right) \left(1+i \sqrt{7}\right)}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right) \log \left(\frac{\left(-i+\sqrt{3}\right) \left(1-i \sqrt{7}\right)}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right)}{\sqrt{7}}+\frac{i \pi ^2 \log \left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right)}{2 \sqrt{7}}+\frac{5 \pi  \log \left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right) \log \left(-\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right)}{3 \sqrt{7}}+\frac{13 i \pi ^2 \log \left(i-\sqrt{7}\right)}{18 \sqrt{7}}+\frac{2 \pi  \log (32) \log \left(i-\sqrt{7}\right)}{3 \sqrt{7}}+\frac{2 i \log \left(\frac{-i+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right) \log \left(\frac{\left(-i+\sqrt{3}\right) \left(1-i \sqrt{7}\right)}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right) \log \left(-i+\sqrt{7}\right)}{\sqrt{7}}+\frac{i \log ^2\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right) \log \left(\left(-1+\sqrt[3]{-1}\right) \left(-i+\sqrt{7}\right)\right)}{\sqrt{7}}+\frac{i \pi ^2 \log \left(\left(i+\sqrt{3}\right) \left(1+i \sqrt{7}\right)\right)}{\sqrt{7}}+\frac{2 i \log \left(\frac{i+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right) \log \left(\frac{\left(i+\sqrt{3}\right) \left(1+i \sqrt{7}\right)}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right) \log \left(3+i \sqrt{7}\right)}{\sqrt{7}}+\frac{2 \pi  \log (3) \log \left(7+i \sqrt{7}\right)}{\sqrt{7}}+\frac{4 \pi  \log \left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right) \log \left(7+i \sqrt{7}\right)}{\sqrt{7}}+\frac{i \log ^2\left(i+\sqrt{3}\right) \log \left(3-i \sqrt{7}\right)}{\sqrt{7}}+\frac{i \log ^2\left(\frac{-i+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right) \log \left(3-i \sqrt{7}\right)}{\sqrt{7}}+\frac{i \log ^2\left(\frac{\left(-i+\sqrt{3}\right) \left(1-i \sqrt{7}\right)}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right) \log \left(3-i \sqrt{7}\right)}{\sqrt{7}}+\frac{i \log (64) \log \left(i+\sqrt{3}\right) \log \left(3-i \sqrt{7}\right)}{3 \sqrt{7}}+\frac{4 \pi  \log \left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right) \log \left(7-i \sqrt{7}\right)}{\sqrt{7}}+\frac{2 \pi  \log (3) \log \left(\frac{1}{448} \left(7-i \sqrt{7}\right)\right)}{\sqrt{7}}-\frac{i \log (4) \log ^2\left(i-\sqrt{3}\right)}{\sqrt{7}}-\frac{i \log (4) \log ^2\left(i+\sqrt{3}\right)}{\sqrt{7}}-\frac{i \log \left(i-\sqrt{7}\right) \log ^2\left(-\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right)}{\sqrt{7}}-\frac{i \log \left(\frac{\left(i+\sqrt{3}\right) \left(1+i \sqrt{7}\right)}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right) \log ^2\left(\left(-1+\sqrt[3]{-1}\right) \left(-i+\sqrt{7}\right)\right)}{\sqrt{7}}-\frac{i \log ^2\left(\frac{\left(-i+\sqrt{3}\right) \left(1-i \sqrt{7}\right)}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right) \log \left(\frac{\left(i+\sqrt{3}\right) \left(1+i \sqrt{7}\right)}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right)}{\sqrt{7}}-\frac{i \log ^2\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right) \log \left(\frac{\left(i+\sqrt{3}\right) \left(1+i \sqrt{7}\right)}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right)}{\sqrt{7}}-\frac{i \log ^2\left(\frac{i-\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right) \log \left(\frac{\left(-i+\sqrt{3}\right) \left(1-i \sqrt{7}\right)}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right)}{\sqrt{7}}-\frac{i \log ^2\left(-\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right) \log \left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right)}{\sqrt{7}}-\frac{4 \pi  \log (7) \log \left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right)}{\sqrt{7}}-\frac{8 \pi  \log (8) \log \left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right)}{\sqrt{7}}-\frac{i \log ^2\left(i+\sqrt{3}\right) \log \left(-i+\sqrt{7}\right)}{\sqrt{7}}-\frac{i \log ^2\left(\frac{-i+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right) \log \left(-i+\sqrt{7}\right)}{\sqrt{7}}-\frac{i \log ^2\left(\sqrt[6]{-1} \left(1+i \sqrt{7}\right)\right) \log \left(-(-1)^{2/3} \left(-i+\sqrt{7}\right)\right)}{\sqrt{7}}-\frac{2 i \log \left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right) \log \left(\frac{\left(i+\sqrt{3}\right) \left(1+i \sqrt{7}\right)}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right) \log \left(\left(-1+\sqrt[3]{-1}\right) \left(-i+\sqrt{7}\right)\right)}{\sqrt{7}}-\frac{2 i \log (4) \log \left(-i-\sqrt{3}\right) \log \left(\left(1-i \sqrt{3}\right) \left(-i+\sqrt{7}\right)\right)}{\sqrt{7}}-\frac{i \log ^2\left(-i+\sqrt{3}\right) \log \left(3+i \sqrt{7}\right)}{\sqrt{7}}-\frac{i \log ^2\left(\frac{i+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right) \log \left(3+i \sqrt{7}\right)}{\sqrt{7}}-\frac{i \log ^2\left(\frac{\left(i+\sqrt{3}\right) \left(1+i \sqrt{7}\right)}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right) \log \left(3+i \sqrt{7}\right)}{\sqrt{7}}-\frac{2 i \log \left(\frac{-i+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right) \log \left(\frac{\left(-i+\sqrt{3}\right) \left(1-i \sqrt{7}\right)}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right) \log \left(3-i \sqrt{7}\right)}{\sqrt{7}}-\frac{i \log ^3\left(-\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right)}{3 \sqrt{7}}-\frac{i \log ^3\left(-\frac{i+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right)}{3 \sqrt{7}}-\frac{i \pi ^2 \log \left(i+\sqrt{3}\right)}{3 \sqrt{7}}-\frac{5 \pi  \log \left(i-\sqrt{7}\right) \log \left(\left(-1-i \sqrt{3}\right) \left(-i+\sqrt{7}\right)\right)}{3 \sqrt{7}}-\frac{i \pi ^2 \log \left(\left(1-i \sqrt{3}\right) \left(-i+\sqrt{7}\right)\right)}{3 \sqrt{7}}-\frac{\pi  \log \left(i-\sqrt{7}\right) \log \left(\left(i+\sqrt{3}\right) \left(1+i \sqrt{7}\right)\right)}{3 \sqrt{7}}-\frac{5 \pi  \log ^2\left(-\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right)}{6 \sqrt{7}}-\frac{4 i \pi ^2 \log \left(\left(-i+\sqrt{3}\right) \left(1-i \sqrt{7}\right)\right)}{9 \sqrt{7}}-\frac{i \pi ^2 \log (45671926166590716193865151022383844364247891968)}{36 \sqrt{7}} ...\text{and so on (that means many other terms)}$$

Comment: Perhaps you could have written, "...and so on", after the first 10 or so terms, which would already give the idea.

Comment: Yes, of course it can be simplified ! For instance, write $45671926166590716193865151022383844364247891968$ as $2^{155}$, and then use $\ln a^b=b\ln a$. :-$)$

Comment: @Lucian: LOL ;)

Comment: @Lucian (+1) great improvement ;)

Comment: @Lucian how did u just know that was a power of 2?

Comment: @frogeyedpeas For example, http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=45671926166590716193865151022383844364247891968

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After lots of simplifications I got this simpler form:
$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln(x)\ln\left(x^2-x+1\right)}{x^2-x+2}\, dx\\=\frac1{648\sqrt7}\Big[71\!\;\pi^3-522\!\;\alpha\!\;\pi^2-54\!\;\big(4\!\;\alpha^3-3\!\;\alpha\ln^2\xi-24\!\;\beta\big)\\+27\!\;\pi\!\;\big(28\!\;\alpha^2-2\!\;(16\!\;\gamma+\ln^22)+(4\ln2-9\ln\xi)\cdot\ln\xi\big)\Big]$$
where

> $$\alpha=\arctan\big(\sqrt7\big)$$

$$\beta=\Im\left[2\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{1+i\sqrt7}4\right)-\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{1-2\!\;i\sqrt3+i\sqrt7}2\right)\\+2 \operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{i+\sqrt3}\eta\right)-2 \operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{i-\sqrt3}\eta\right)-\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{\xi-3\!\;i\sqrt3+i\sqrt7}8\right)\right]$$

> $$\gamma=\Re\left[\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{i+\sqrt3}\eta\right)\right]$$

$$\xi=5-\sqrt{21}$$

> $$\eta=\sqrt3+\sqrt7$$

Comment: This looks far far nicer! (+1) :-)

Comment: I have a feeling that $\beta$ could be simplified a little further, but so far I was not successful in it.

Answer (score 5):

Let
\begin{align}\tag{1}
a &= \frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}  \hspace{10mm} \alpha = \frac{1 + i \sqrt{7}}{2} \\
b &= \frac{1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}  \hspace{10mm} \beta = \frac{1 - i \sqrt{7}}{2}
\end{align}
to take the integral
\begin{align}\tag{2}
I = \int_0^1 \frac{\log (x) \log \left(x^2-x+1\right)}{x^2-x+2} \, dx
\end{align}
into the form
\begin{align}\tag{3}
I = \int_0^1 \frac{\log (x) \, [ \ln(x-a) + \ln(x-b)]}{(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)} \, dx
\end{align}
and break up the integral into 4 integrals and see what goes from there.

---

One may also consider the form
\begin{align}\tag{4}
J(x,y; a) = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{t^{x} \, (t-a)^{y}}{(t-\alpha)(t-\beta)} \, dt 
\end{align}
and take the first derivative with respect to $x$ and $y$. Indeed
\begin{align}\tag{5}
I = \partial_{x,y} \left[J(x,y; a) + J(x,y;b) \right]_{x,y=0}.
\end{align}
A fundamental form may be
\begin{align}\tag{6}
J_{1}(x,y;a;\alpha) = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{t^{x} \, (t-a)^{y}}{t- \alpha} \, dt
\end{align}
for which
\begin{align}
J(x,y;a) = \frac{1}{\alpha - \beta} \left( J_{1}(x,y;a;\alpha) - J_{1}(x,y;a;\beta) \right)
\end{align}

Comment: (+1) Let's see what happens ...